# android ошибка сохранения скриншота в галерею

Tags: android, файлы, файловая-система, screenshots, fileoutputstream

в моем приложении я снимаю видео с помощью камеры, далее я это видео произвожу благодаря

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
{
    Surface s = new Surface(surface);

    try
    {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(getVideoFilePath());
        mp.setSurface(s);
        mp.prepare();

        mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);

        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setPreviewSize(true);
        mp.start();
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

я реализовал метод программного скриншота,

```
  public void getBitmap(TextureView vv)
{
    String mPath = getAndroidImageFolder().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM_dd-HHmmss").format(new Date()) + "cameraRecorder.png";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Capturing Screenshot: " + mPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Bitmap bm = vv.getBitmap();
    if(bm == null)
        Log.e(TAG,"bitmap is null");

    OutputStream fout = null;
    File imageFile = new File(mPath);

    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fout);
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "FileNotFoundException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Но скриншот не появляется в галерее и выбивает ошибку
Вот что выдает в Logcat

```
 E/TextureViewActivity: FileNotFoundException
11-14 15:25:09.961 4143-4143/com. W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/201811_14-152509cameraRecorder.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-14 15:25:09.971 4143-4143/com. W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
11-14 15:25:09.971 4143-4143/com. W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
11-14 15:25:09.971 4143-4143/com. W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
11-14 15:25:09.971 4143-4143/com. W/System.err:     at com. 
 camera.VideoProcessor.getBitmap(VideoProcessor.java:245)
11-14 15:25:09.971 4143-4143/com. W/System.err:     at com.camera.VideoProcessor.onClick(VideoProcessor.java:369)
```

> Вот на какой участок кода выбивает ошибку

```
at com.camera.VideoProcessor.getBitmap(VideoProcessor.java:247)  ->  fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
```

Буду вам очень благодарен за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется ты картинку не регестрируешь в фотоальбоме. Вот этого не хватает:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
```

Я давно как то сохранял **screenshot** следующим кодом:

```
public void storeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String filePath, Context context) {

    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();

    try {
        filePath += "/FolderNew/";
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Picture New");
        file.mkdir();
        file = new File(filePath, context.getString(R.string.app_name) + "_" + Integer.toString(time.year) + "_" + Integer.toString(time.month + 1) + "_" + Integer.toString(time.monthDay) + "_" + Integer.toString(time.hour) + "_" + Integer.toString(time.minute) + ".jpg"); // создать уникальное имя для файла основываясь на дате сохранения

        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fOut); // сохранять картинку в jpeg-формате с 85% сжатия.
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        adress = file.getName();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName()); // регистрация в фотоальбоме

      //  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "11storeBitmap = " + MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName()).toString()); // регистрация в фотоальбоме

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Надеюсь тебе поможет

Comment: да, спасибо.еще есть вопрос сможешь помочь?

Comment: спрашивай, посмотрим на твой вопрос

Comment: @YuryMatalov https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907531/android-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-arraylist